# LDAP Response timeout not working with Unboundid SDK

Tags: java, ldap, unboundid-ldap-sdk

I am trying to get the names of all groupOfUniqueNames objects using the Unboundid LDAP SDK. I am able to do it, but have a problem if the server has a lot of entries. Setting the response timeout seems to be ignored, and the program just hangs (waiting for the large response), instead of terminating after 5000 milliseconds.

I have come to understand that I can use paging to return a certain amount of users at a time, however, I am concerned as to why the timeout isn't working.

```
SearchResult searchResult;

    Filter filter = 
            Filter.createEqualityFilter("objectClass", "groupOfUniqueNames");

    try {
        SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest(baseDN, SearchScope.SUB, filter, "uniqueMember", "member");

        searchRequest.setResponseTimeout(5000);
        System.out.println(searchRequest.getResponseTimeout(connection));   // prints 5000

        searchResult = connection.search(searchRequest);

    } catch(LDAPSearchException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    for (SearchResultEntry entry : searchResult.getSearchEntries()) {
        String name = entry.getDN();
        System.out.println(name);
    }
```

What is perplexing to me is that the above code will always hang, however I've had other searches that timeout properly (with error 85 - client timeout).

What could the reason be for this particular query ignoring the client timeout? The documentation [here](https://docs.ldap.com/ldap-sdk/docs/javadoc/com/unboundid/ldap/sdk/LDAPConnectionOptions.html) makes it sound like, no matter what, after 5000 milliseconds the program will stop waiting for a response.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the similar problem:

```
LDAP Error Code 85 - A client-side timeout was encountered
```

In my case I had to configure SSL for LDAP connection.
For example, see this as temp implementation:

```
 SSLUtil sslUtil = new SSLUtil(new TrustAllTrustManager());
 SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = sslUtil.createSSLSocketFactory();
 LDAPConnection connection = new LDAPConnection(sslSocketFactory);
```

https://docs.ldap.com/ldap-sdk/docs/javadoc/com/unboundid/util/ssl/SSLUtil.html

I think that words about "timeout" are very confusing in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Try the *synchronous mode* I.e. do this before you connect to server:

```java
connectionOptions.setUseSynchronousMode(true);
// more options
connection.setConnectionOptions(connectionOptions);
```